# Not sure how to find my switch?

Tags: switch, reset

newbie question, I'm afraid:

I got a second hand (or maybe more) Cisco WS-C2948G switch off eBay for use at home, but the thing came with no documentation and no software. I'm not a sysadmin, and I haven't got a clue (clearly) how to talk to the thing, or configure it.

Is there a complete idiot's guide to finding, connecting to, resetting and configuring your 2948G for dummies? Where would I find it, because the manuals on the Cisco site assume either more knowledge than I have, or a factory default setting, which I also don't seem to have.

I'm trying to connect to it using the 10BT MGT port and a crossover cable, from a laptop that is also connected to the net via a wireless adapter. When I do a netstat I don't see anything that isn't just my other machines, or my ISP.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not start with the management guide?

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps606/products_configuration_guide_chapter09186a008007d10e.html

It should cover everything you need. But to get you started.

You need a direct console connection (com port connection), configure your terminal emulation program for 9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity, and 1 stop bit. You need a cisco console cable (blue one) for that switch if I recall correctly. The RJ-45 goes in the console port of the switch, the other end to your local com port. You can find more info about the cabling here:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps332/products_tech_note09186a0080094ce6.shtml

To use the IP management you need the IP address and port of the switch first. You can configure these over the direct console connection.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, the Cisco Console Cable jacks look like RJ-45 but the pin-out is different.  As Pehrs said (I upvoted his answer), RTFM (this isn't a quick-n-dirty question; you need to know what you're doing) and get yourself a console cable.  It'll be baby-blue and flat (non-twisted-pair).

In windows you would use Hyperterminal to interact with the console.  I don't know the commands to hook your BSD terminal app to the serial port, unfortunately.

[image: cisco_8P8C-DB9 cable]

Answer (score 0):

Ahh the 2948G - that will (if I remember correctly) run the CAT os not the Cisco IOS. a bit different than the standard. You do indeed need a console cable to start though.
They should be easy enough to find.